# Asynchronous rest calls non sequential in Java

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, java-8, nio

I have multiple synchronous calls to third party applications in my one call. 
I am using Spring RestTemplate to give a call to third party application as below,

```
Class B {
   public void makeRestCall(String url){
      Collection response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Collection.class, params);
      return response;
   }
}
```

I have a call from my controller

```
Class A {

    public List<Data> getAllData(){
         // Some Business Logic
         String url1 = "htpp://anyurl1";
         // Some Processing based on Logic
         String url2 = "htpp://anyurl2";
         B b = new B()
         b.makeRestCall(url1);
         b.makeRestCall(url2);

        // Club together data from both calls

        // Again some rest calls based on business logic
        }
    }
```

Right now, as I make a rest call my rest code is blocked until I get the response back from the requested URL.
I have tried using AsyncRestTemplate and SimpleReact API, but I am facing following issues. I have a series of rest calls sequentially and I can't directly provide the list of urls in below code as I don't want to mix the rest call code with my actual application flow.

```
new SimpleReact()
.fromStream(urls.stream()
        .map(it ->  
            toCompletableFuture(template
                        .getForEntity(it,String.class))))
.then(it -> it.getBody())
.then(it -> extractTitle(it))
```

If someone can help on how can I make async rest calls in my case.

Comment: Can you clarify *I have a series of rest calls sequentially and I can't directly provide the list of urls in below code as I don't want to mix the rest call code with my actual application flow.* ?

Comment: Right now, I have all third party calls happening from this piece of code. So, based on my business logic I might have a third party call which internally calls this code.

Comment: I have edited my question. Do you have idea on how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I guess it might be how to bridge the gap between some sample simple-react code and the op's own code?

If it helps, you don't have to use the URLs as input into simple-react, you can use any Java 8 Supplier for example. Just using the standard Spring RestTemplate (i.e. non NIO synchronous Rest calls) you can make the code asynchronous with something like this in simple-react -

e.g.

```
 List<Results> results = new SimpleReact().react( () -> makeRestCall(url1),
                                                  () -> makeRestCall(url2), 
                                                  ..etc..)
                                          .block();
```

or even further abstracted

```
   List<Results> results = new SimpleReact().react( supplier1,supplier2, ..etc..)
                  .block();
```

If you want to plug in the NIO  AsyncRestTemplate (really for occasions where you are making a massive number of async calls and need to get away from using a thread-per-request) - you can modify makeRestCall to use the AsyncRestTemplate and return a CompletableFuture. You can push those CompletableFutures into simple-react as follows

```
 List<Results> results = new SimpleReact().fromStream(Stream.of(
                                                      makeRestCall(url1),
                                                      makeRestCall(url2))
                                          .block();
```

There is an example of using async NIO Rest clients with simple-react in another of our open source projects  Microserver. e.g.  (https://github.com/aol/micro-server/blob/master/micro-core/src/test/java/app/async/com/aol/micro/server/AsyncResource.java )